# _set_sbh_threshold in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to port an application that was developed with VS 2008. I have imported project into VS 2010 and built it. I have got several errors, related to `_set_sbh_threshold` function. In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6x53890%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) I have found that this function doesn't supported by Windows Vista or Windows 7. Also this function was removed from the VS 2010 *malloc.h* file. So, is there any equivalent functions in VS 2010? Maybe there is no sense to use this function at all in new Windows?

Comment: Use the same framework 2.0 or 3.5 that was used in VS 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Windows Vista onwards do not use this value for setting the SBH size, there is no point is setting it via that function.  If what you are looking for is a single version of code that will run as intended across all Windows versions from 95 onwards then you are out of luck and will have to maintain 2 separate versions.

Comment: Bad news for me. Thank you for the answer.